# How to ping a website and write results in a Chart?

Tags: php, content-management-system, admin, ping

I am developing a small CMS for a website to a client but I am stuck on this question. My client wants a site to `ping` another server and show the results on the webpage.

I have this in my index.php:

```
<?php
include_once "pingdomain.php";
?>
Test Page Ping: <?php echo pingDomain('www.adhenrique.com.br'); ?> ms <br>
<?php
echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='1;'>";
?>
```

So, I wanted to get the result of `<?php echo pingDomain('www.adhenrique.com.br'); ?>` and put it on a chart.

I'm on the right track? Is it possible?

Comment: What does `pingDomain()` return? Instead of `echo`'ing the result, you may store it in a variable to display in a chart later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for pinging a specified domain or ip address.
https://github.com/geerlingguy/Ping

Then save the results into your database, a text file, any medium you like or directly get results from the ping and use a charting library to visualize them.

I'm quite happy with http://www.chartjs.org/ for visualizing data.

Comment: This class returns me an error on line 12 of pingtest.php
Doesn't work. =//

Comment: @ADHenrique you are running the PHPUnit file. It's working as expected like this.

    `<?php
    
    require_once('ping.php');
    use JJG\Ping as Ping;

    $reachable_host = 'www.google.com';
    $ping = new Ping($reachable_host);
    $latency = $ping->ping('exec');
    echo $latency;`